# Convert dates to dates with a first day of the month in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There are dates, for example:

```
'2022-10-11'
'2022-01-20'
'2022-12-31'
```

How to convert them to the following dates in Snowflake?

```
'2022-10-01'
'2022-01-01'
'2022-12-01'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you! I'd like to mark it as a solution if you put it not in the comment but as a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be achieved with `DATE_TRUNC` function:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',  col_name) FROM ...
```